# C# equivalent of a Java class with multiple Setter methods

Tags: java, c#, setter, getter-setter

I am trying to write a C# version of a Java class. If we call our class `MyRequest`, we are dealing with a field called `_body` which is a `JSONObject`. Here is a simplified version of my class with only this field.

**Java:**

```
public class MyRequest {


    JSONObject _body = new JSONObject();

    /**
     * Pass a String formatted json as the request body
     * @param json
     * @return the request itself
     */
    public MyRequest setBody(String json) {
        _body = new JSONObject(json);
        return this;
    }

        /**
     * Pass a JSONObject formatted json as the request body
     * @param json
     * @return the request itself
     */
    public MyRequest setBody(JSONObject json) {
        return setBody(json.toString());
    }

    /**
     * Use an HashMap to build the body
     * @param json
     * @return the request itself
     */
    public MyRequest setBody(HashMap<String, Object> json) {
        _body = new JSONObject(json);
        return this;
    }

    /**
     * Body getter
     * @return the stringified body
     */
    public String getBody() {
        return _body.toString();
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return new JSONObject()
                .put("Resource", _resource)
                .put("ID", _id)
                .put("Action", _action)
                .put("Action ID", _actionId)
                .put("Filters", _filters.toString())
                .put("Body", _body.toString())
                .toString();
    }
}
```

As we can see our `_body` field has three different setters and the class also overrides the `ToString()` method. I'd like to write a C# equivalent to this class without calling my getter and setter methods `GetBody()` and `SetBody()`.

The equivalent for `JSONObject` in C# will be a `JObject` which comes from [Newtonsoft JSON](https://www.nuget.org/packages/newtonsoft.json/) library. I have written the override as following (this however is not the main problem):

```
public override string ToString()
{
    return new JObject()
       {
          {"Body",_body.ToString()}
       }.ToString();
}
```

I would like the class to follow C# coding standards. They usually come with a pattern like this:

```
private int myVar;

public int MyProperty
{
    get { return myVar; }
    set { myVar = value; }
}
```

So how can we have the same behavior for this Java class in C#?

Comment: What is the actual purpose of `MyRequest` class? It seems to me that these are actually more methods then setters to your class.

Comment: C# properties will also have a `value` in their `set`-method of the same given data-type. So in your example in the end, `value` will always be an `int`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would normally have a property with the same type as you want to expose with the getter, and then have additional `SetBody` methods. So *potentially*:

```
private JObject body;

public string Body
{
    get { return body.ToString(); }
    set { body = JObject.Parse(value); }
}

public void SetBody(JObject body)
{
    this.body = body;
}

public void SetBody(IDictionary<string, object> body)
{
    ...
}
```

However:

- You might want to clone the `JObject` in the `SetBody(JObject)` method, as otherwise it will behave quite oddly
- Using a `string` property with an underlying `JObject` variable could end up being expensive... evaluating a property is *usually* expected to be cheap.

Comment: Makes sense. I don't quite understand the cloning part though. Aren't we supposed to set the current instance's property? Could you add that bit to your answer please?

Comment: @Disasterkid: Cloning the *parameter* - to isolate your object from future changes to the one referred to by the `SetBody` method. Otherwise you're leaking the implementation detail that *really* the underlying variable is a `JObject`. (For example, changes to the dictionary passed into `SetBody(IDictionary<,>)` would presumably have no effect.)

Answer (score 1):

Properties in C# are unique. You can't have two properties with the same name and a different data type (or with the same data type).

That said, there is no other way to achieve this other than using methods to set the body in a specialized way. The `Set...` construction is a good practice in C# too. Just create a single property (of the data type which is the most complex, like `JObject`), and `Set...` methods for the rest.

If you want to set it on initialization of the class, a set of overloaded constructors would be an option too. (If you need to, create a few overloaded constructors, not a dozen of them)

Of course, you can create dummy properties to set a value, but that is a very bad practice in my opinion.